# Show the date (Column Title) in which a specific number occurs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have done a few days research to attempt to figure this out on my own. I have a spreadsheet that I have created that will track completed items completed and their completion dates.

Here's the issue: I am working on approximately 400 buses. I need to track when the repairs are completed. The image included will show the sheet to date. The numbers at the bottom (101, 102, 103, etc.) will serve as Bus Numbers. I need to then take the completed buses and track them on a separate sheet as to their date of completion.

Essentially, wherever Bus 101 occurs, I would like the date at the top of the column to fill in automatically on another Excel tab.

[Daily Bus Checklist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46xRW.png)

Comment: must the bus numbers be split across 5 rows like that, makes this really difficult...

Answer (score 0):

Works to calculate the first 5 rows, can be repeated for the next 5 once you get the gist of it.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Summary!2:2,MATCH(B1,Summary!12:12,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Summary!2:2,MATCH(B1,Summary!13:13,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Summary!2:2,MATCH(B1,Summary!14:14,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Summary!2:2,MATCH(B1,Summary!15:15,0)),IFERROR(INDEX(Summary!2:2,MATCH(B1,Summary!16:16,0)),"")))))`

I done the data horizontally as your main tab is layed out that way, happy to tweak if you need.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Bus 101 is always in Row 12, from what your sheet looks like, but can be amended if it would be spread over 5 rows:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lastColumn As Long, vNumber As Integer, o As Long
Dim vDate() As Double

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    lastColumn = .Cells(2, 255).End(xlToLeft).Column
    vNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(12, 5), .Cells(12, lastColumn)), 101)
    ReDim vDate(1 To vNumber)
    o = 1
    For i = 5 To lastColumn
        If .Cells(12, i) = 101 Then
            vDate(o) = .Cells(2, i).Value
            o = o + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

With this you have an array of the dates.. I am not sure if you need help with getting that on the sheet and so on...